# YouNet social contact importer plugin not working during signup

Tags: php, socialengine

When performing the sign-up process, and selected to import my GMail contacts and granted permission to Younet OpenID service, the signup window went blank after clicking "accept". And now I can not advance to a next step. What may be the reason for this. Please help me to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reason. Please make sure you have added the google id needed for inviting for contacts in the admin section.

Fast way is that you contact the younet for this or post the error log here.

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav..I haven't found any portion for adding google id in admin section..The error that i am getting at console is  TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
 

this.tabs=document.getElementById(tabinterfaceid).getElementsByTagName("a") //Ge...

Comment: you should contact the younet for this. May be you need to install the latest package of the plugin.